# Test login to a Laravel site with JMeter

Tags: laravel, jmeter

I am trying to test a site in Laravel with Jmeter. The first step is the login. I access the login page and with a CSS/JQuery Extractor I get the token and then I post the login using the credentials and that token, but the server responds 419.

[image]

GET http://localhost/login

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/login">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="dw97NBXrOIeKgpwG9FjS8zb53GUC2VHKsoYP4NLZ">
```

POST http://localhost/login

```
POST data:
_token=b1nfiVLOGyfADk7nxIYgLvfshrSOs94L0ylOg4o4&email=myemail&password=12345678

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
X-CSRF-TOKEN: b1nfiVLOGyfADk7nxIYgLvfshrSOs94L0ylOg4o4
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 96
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.6 (java 1.5)
```

POST login response:

```
Error Count: 1
Response code: 419
Response message: unknown status
```

How can I make this work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the version of JMeter used for the testing? It looks like you are using an older version of JMeter. It does not matter. But it is better to move to the latest version. Current version is 5.2.1

Comment: 1. Can you confirm that the email and passwords are valid and you can login to the system through web browser? 2. Can you provide screenshot of the second HTTP request ?

Comment: @JaneshKodikara thanks! But yes, the email and password are valid. if I disable VerifyCsrfToken middleware everything works.

Answer (score 2):

1. Looking into [List of HTTP Status Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#Unofficial_codes):

   > **419 Page Expired** ([Laravel Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel))
   >
   > Used by the Laravel Framework when a **CSRF Token is missing or expired**.
2. Looking into [X-CSRF-TOKEN chapter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token) of Laravel documennation passing the token as a [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request parameter might be not enough

   > In addition to checking for the CSRF token as a POST parameter, the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware will also check for the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` request header

So my expectation is that you need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/) and configure it to send `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header with the value of `${token}`

[image]

Comment: Exactly that I tried, but it doesn't work. It is very rare, because the token is included in the header and in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Its helps me, I am add HTTP Header Manager into the Thread Group, and set Name : X-CSRF-TOKEN, Value: ${_token}.

**In CSS Extractor**
Name of created variable : csrfToken
CSS Selector expression: input[name=_token]
Attribute: value
Match No.(0 for Random)  : 0
Default Value : Toke Not  found

Passed variable to http request parameter, Name : _token, Value : ${csrfToken} (csrf_Token is Created Variable which is passed from the CSS Extractor) check each http request and passed _token value.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).